# Removing duplicate records based on a timestamp and numeric when the timestamp or numeric doesn't match perfectly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains call records.  Sometimes, 2 records get created for a single call.  I have a process in place that compares the time of the call (call_date), duration of the call (duration), source number (src), and destination number (dst).  If all 4 fields match exactly, all except for one record gets deleted.

Matching against the src and dst is no problem.  However, sometimes the call_date is off by 1-2 seconds or the duration is off by a fraction of a second which prevents the duplicate from being deleted.  Sometimes the duration is off by a few milliseconds that also prevents the duplicate from being deleted.

Also, the duration is a numeric field, measured in seconds, that goes to 3 decimal places.  I can round the duration to the nearest second to catch a lot of the duplicates, but if one record has a duration of, say, 10.454 seconds and another with 10.513, then it will round to 10 and 11, respectively.  I can't use a floor or ceiling function because I'll run into a similar issue when the durations are 10.918 and 11.142 seconds.

So I have the numeric and timestamp field that can be off by just a little bit even though they're truly duplicate records.  Is there a way to add some "fudge room" to the query to look for duplicates within a 1 second difference in duration and timestamp?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to disallow the duplicate calls from being recorded to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that approach, but it won't be possible to prevent it at the source for at least 6 months.  It has something to do with migrating customers between voice servers and calls being routed between the old and new server in the meantime.  Not really my area.

Comment: Use `DATEDIFF(seconds,column1,column2) > 1` for the date columns, and `(duration1 - duration2) > 1` for the duration (note: if either duration can be the greater value add `OR (duration2 - duration 1) > 1`).

Comment: @Turophile One can use `ABS()` for duration instead of two conditions.

Comment: @Turophile there is one date column and one duration column.  The comparison needs to happen across multiple rows.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you would fill in the blanks. `FROM table1 AS A, table1 AS B WHERE DATEDIFF(seconds,a.timestamp_col,b.timestamp_col) > 1` etc etc

Comment: @Vesper - I looked for an ABS() function, but didn't see one for SQL Server on the reference pages I was using - Searched again now and found it, and I agree, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, that would be:

```
delete 
from table1 as a
where exists (
  select 1
  from table1 as b 
  where a.src = b.src
  and   a.dst = b.dst
  and   a.call_date >= b.call_date
  and   ABS(a.duration - b.duration) <= 1
  and   DATEDIFF(seconds,b.call_date,a.call_date) <= 1
  );
```

Here's what I ended up using

```
delete from #tbl# where id in (
select a.id
from #tbl# as a
where a.call_date >= DateAdd(day, -31, GETDATE())
and a.duration_msec > 0
and a.ani <> ''
and a.transaction_id is null
and exists (
   select 1
   from #tbl# as b 
   where b.call_date >= DateAdd(day, -31, GETDATE())
   and b.duration_msec > 0
   and b.ani <> ''
   and b.transaction_id is null
   and a.ani = b.ani
   and (a.translated_num = b.translated_num or a.dialed_num = b.dialed_num)
   and ABS(a.duration_msec - b.duration_msec) <= 1
   and ABS(DATEDIFF(second,b.call_date,a.call_date)) <= 1
   and a.id > b.id
   )
)
```

Comment: **Note:** I had the `a.call_date > b.call_date` to ensure you are deleting all but the earliest one, but if the dates are exactly the same, both will be kept. I now changed the code to `a.call_date >= b.call_date` but that will delete both if they are identical. To avoid this, you need some other test to determine which one to keep.

Comment: Thanks again.  I noticed this as well.  I simplified the problem for the sake of the post.  Here's the final query that I landed on:

Comment: uhg.... can't put code neatly in comments.  See my answer edit.  I have a unique integer ID field that I used to differentiate.